# Http GET method Error while calling REST wcf service

Tags: android, wcf, http, execute, http-get

```
public void callService()
    {  
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",latitude));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",longitude));
        try {
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = hc.execute(postMethod);  // not able to execute the statement.
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) 
        {
                InputStream inStream = null;
                try {
                    inStream = entity.getContent();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                result= convertStreamToString(inStream);
                Log.i("---------------- Result",result);
        }
    } // end callService()
```

We are trying to call a WCF Rest service from my android device, above is the code for the same,
I found out that the code is terminating after this statement in the code : **response = hc.execute(postMethod);** 
Any help in this context will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the log say when execution stops?

Comment: "execution stops" may be connection attempt timing out. Are you sure that server is accessible from android device?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your post:

Are you sending a POST to a REST service that only allows a GET?